# Replace int numbers with the corresponding months(strings) without using If-else

Tags: c#, if-statement

What is the best way to do this task without using the if-else clause 12 times. The task is this:

```
if(mon=="1")
{
 month="JAN";
}
else if(mon=="2")
{
 month="FEB";
}
```

and so on..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using this code

```
using System.Globalization;

var month = 7;
var dtf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
string monthName = dtf.GetMonthName(month);
string abbreviatedMonthName = dtf.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative for this is to use array.

```
string[] months = new string[]{"JAN", "FEB", "MAR",..., "DEC"};
string month = months[value - 1];
```

`-1` because the index starts at zero.

or

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1)
```

Comment: A check on `value` is required.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Globalization;
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames[int.Parse(mon)-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Switch-Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
switch(mon)
{
    case "1":
            month = "JAN";
            break;
    case "2":
            month = "FEB";
            break;
    default:
            month = string.Empty; // OR throw exception
            break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
switch (int.parse(mon))
{
    case 1: return "JAN";
    case 2: return "FEB";
    //...
    case 12: return "DEC";
    default: return "???";
}

// Azodious notes that switches work on strings too, so you can also do:
switch (mon)
{
    case "1": return "JAN";
    case "2": return "FEB";
    //...
    case "12": return "DEC";
    default: return "???";
}
```

or as an index into an array, similar to what John Woo showed, (but you'd have to parse `mon` as an `int` first).